# Add to array that is manually added attribute on object in collection

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

Adding services to a collection if their related agreement is out of date or nearing its end date.  This part works fine.  However, as this is just one section, I would like to add the issue reason to the object (eg next section will highlight hardware issues).

This is OK for the first iteration, but if a service has more than one issue that needs to be recorded I can't use `setAttribute()` (as it just overrides the previous entry) and am having trouble getting any other method working (like `add()` or `push()`, `filter()`).

Code around it is:

```
$issuesCollection = collect([]);

$agreementsRed = Agreement::with('services')->whereDate('expiry_date', '<', Carbon::today()->toDateString())
        ->orderBy('vendor', 'asc')
        ->get();

foreach ($agreementsRed as $agreement) {
foreach ($agreement->services as $service) {
    if (!$issuesCollection->contains('service_full_name', $service->service_full_name)) {
                $issuesCollection->push($service);
                $service->setAttribute('issues', ['Agreement out of date - ' . $agreement->vendor]);
            } else {
                // add new item to issues array on object in collection
            }
        }
    }

$agreementsAmber = Agreement::with('services')->whereBetween('expiry_date', array(Carbon::today()->toDateString(), $amberDate->toDateString()))
        ->orderBy('vendor', 'asc')
        ->get();

foreach ($agreementsAmber as $agreement) {
foreach ($agreement->services as $service) {
            if (!$issuesCollection->contains('service_full_name', $service->service_full_name)) {
                $issuesCollection->push($service);
                $service->setAttribute('issues', ['Agreement nearing end date - ' . $agreement->vendor]);
            } else {
                // add new item to issues array on object in collection
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I push to the array that is in an object in the collection only (it's not on the actual model's object)?

Comment: Do you know that `setAttribute('issues', $value)` is identically assigning value as `$service->issues = $value` ? Create local variable before loop and do assignment after loop, that's all.

Comment: @Chay22 What do you mean by "identically assigning value as `$service->issues = $value`"?  I have a foreach in my view that is displaying `$service->issues` correctly - it's just that there is only ever one issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being the solution to achieve what I was looking for

```
foreach ($agreementsRed as $agreement) {
        foreach ($agreement->services as $service) {
            if (!$issuesCollection->contains('service_full_name', $service->service_full_name)) {
                $issuesCollection->push($service);
                $service->setAttribute('issues', ['Agreement out of date - ' . $agreement->vendor]);
            } else {
                $issuesCollection->filter(function($item) use ($service, $agreement) {
                    if ($item->service_full_name == $service->service_full_name) {
                        $issues_array[0] = $item->issues;
                        array_push($issues_array[0], 'Agreement out of date - ' . $agreement->vendor);
                        $item->issues = $issues_array[0];
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```